# Noise hidden value

Tags: python, xor

This was an interview question that I didn't have the slightest clue how to solve. That interview is over, but I really would like to see what they were looking for. I'm trying to obfuscate this somewhat to respect the company that asked it.

There is a secret integer `S` consisting of `N` bits. Our job is to guess this secret integer with very high certainty.

We can only access `S` via a secret method `foo(G)` which takes in a guess `G` and XOR's that guess with both `S` AND a randomly generated value `V` where each bit in `V` has a 10% chance of being a 1. It then counts the number of 1's and returns that as an integer

```
foo(g):
    generate v
    return bin(g ^ v ^ s).count('1')
```

`V` is generated with each invocation of `foo`
We are only given let's say 100,000 attempts to run `foo` before we fail the interview, or the world explodes or something.

How could we approach this?

The thing that is driving me crazy is that even guessing the correct answer has an N/10 chance of coming back with a non zero value from `foo`. So even a brute force attempt seems off the table.

Comment: Given the results of a number of `foo` calls, [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is a good way to guess `S`, and theoretically optimal in some sense, though potentially too expensive to compute. I don't have time to turn this into a full answer, with a procedure for making guesses and a full explanation and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: If you repeat the function `foo(G)` with the same G for enough times, the average result of `foo(G)` will be close enough to the expectation value.

For example, assume `S` has N bits, M of them are 1, and let `G = N bits of 0`, then the expectation of `foo(G)` will be `E(N,M)=M*0.9 + (N-M)*0.1`. Since we know N, and we can get the average of `foo(G)`, then it's simple to work out what is the number of M. Actually we don't even need to figure out M.

When we have the number `E(N,M)`, then the rest will be simple: iterate i through N, and make the ith bit of G equals to 1, while the rest are zero, and repeat `foo(G)` for sufficient large number of times. If the ith bit of `s` is equal to 1, then the expectation of `foo(G)` will be `E(N-1,M-1)+0.1=E(N,M)-0.8`, otherwise if the ith bit of `S` is equal to 0, the expectation of `foo(G)` will be `E(N-1,M)+0.9=E(N,M)+0.8`.

Then you could work out the value of `S` eventually. The more times you repeat `foo(G)` on the same G, the higher certainty you'll get.

Some example code:

```
import numpy as np

S = 1117506159690372465501725393907 # an 100 bit number

def foo(S, N, G):
    bits = np.random.choice(2, size=N, p=[0.9,0.1])
    V = int("".join(str(b) for b in bits), 2)
    return bin(G^V^S).count('1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 100
    result = np.empty((101,1000))
    for j in range(1000):
        G = int("0" * N, 2)
        result[0,j] = foo(S, N, G)
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(1000):
            G = int("0"*i + "1" + "0"*(N-i-1), 2)
            result[i+1, j] = foo(S, N, G)
    avg = np.mean(result, axis=1)
    avg -= avg[0]
    out = "0b"+"".join("1" if num < 0 else "0" for num in avg[1:])
    print(str(bin(S))==out) # True
```

Comment: This is actually the line I was thinking along. I knew we could get the expected number of bits by inputting 0's. What I couldn't figure out is how that really helped. Thanks.

Comment: @CodySmith Does the above answer help you with your question? Do you need any further explanation on this?

Comment: Nah I think that does it. Humm, I was closer than I thought.

Comment: This works, but it makes very inefficient use of the limited number of guesses available.

Comment: @user2357112 that's true, that's probably the 10min interview solution of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
from random import random as r
from collections import defaultdict

N = 8                # Number of bits
S = 123              # Secret number

stop_iter = 100      # Number of iterations
#stop_tol -- also an option, but seems risky given noise

def foo(g):
    V = int(''.join([str(int(r() < 0.1)) for _ in range(N)]), 2)
    return bin(g ^ V ^ S).count('1')

def test_guess(g, n=10):
    total = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        total += foo(g)
    return total / n

def test_perturb(g, p, n=10):
    g ^= (1 << p)
    return test_guess(g, n)

def test_bit_positions(g):
    deltas = {}
    for i in range(N):
        deltas[i] = test_perturb(g, i)

    return deltas

def itemval(i): return i[1]


history = defaultdict(list)
guess = 0                       # Initial
for _ in range(stop_iter):
    deltas = test_bit_positions(guess)
    error = sum(deltas.values())

    history[guess].append(error)

    (index, delta) = min(deltas.items(), key=itemval)
    guess ^= (1 << index)
    print(guess, bin(guess), "after flipping bit %d" % index, error)

    # If you had to, you could evaluate history at each iteration,
    #   trying to identify a value that has set itself apart
    #   potentially halting early but slowing the program

mean_error = {k:(sum(lst) / len(lst)) for (k,lst) in history.items()}

print()
print("Results:")
mean_error = sorted(mean_error.items(), key=itemval)
for (guess, err) in mean_error[:5]:
    print(guess, err)

print()
print("Guess:", mean_error[0][0])
```

Example Output (N=8, S=123, stop_iter=100, n=10):

```
Results:
123  12.799021276595743
127  17.55975
 59  17.564333333333334
251  17.583
121  17.58742857142857

Guess: 123 (Correct)

Calls to foo(): 8000
```

Example output (N=20, S=12345, stop_iter=100, n=10)

```
Results:
 12345 56.19999999999998
 77881 69.69999999999999
 12601 69.85
274489 69.93333333333334
  8249 70.10000000000001

Guess: 12345 (Correct)

Calls to foo(): 20000
```

Basically iterative optimization, trying to get the `error` term as close to zero as possible, by comparing N perturbed versions of your current guess.  Because of the noise, this will be trickier than usual.

There are also some parameters you have available to tweak, the `n` default argument in the two `test_` functions, and the number of iterations `stop_iter`.